# Multiple SET/MERGE statements in a data step

Tags: eclipse, sas

```
    data _null_;
    set hash.bankholidays;

        retain total 0; 
        format date :date9.;

        set hash.oyster;
            datetime = datepart(datetime);
            format datetime :date9. ;

            if date eq datetime then do;
            total = total + amount; end;


    put "total =" total; 

    run;
```

This gives me a popup dialog box in eclipse: 
`Multiple SET/MERGE statements in a data step`

I'm wondering what's going on here? It seems to be saying that you can't have a set statement within a set statement, but I'm sure I've done it before.

eg.

```
    data data_ex.giftwrap_ribbon_final; 
    set data_ex.giftwrap_w_ribbon_fl; 
        if not missing (first) and not missing (last) then do;
            do i = first to last;
            set data_ex.ribbon (keep=ribbon_colour) point = i;
            output;
            end;
        end; 

        else do;
        ribbon_colour = ''; 
        output; 
        end;
    run;
```

could I get some clarification here?

Also, about that last put. How do I tell it to execute the put after the set statement has finished?

Comment: I've never heard of DataServer, what is that (please give a link). With respect to your code, what do you want that data step to do: print "total" once?  If so, describe the two datasets "bankholidays" and "oyster", including how many obs in each and which contains the three variables (date, datetime, and amount).

Comment: I still can't find any online reference to a product by that name (not saying it doesn't exist, I just can't find it).  At any rate, it sounds like this "Multiple SET/MERGE" error is particular to Dataserver because it is perfectly good SAS syntax. Does CarolinaJay65's answer meet your needs on the second part of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the set statment in a do loop and use pointers.

```
data _null_;
set hash.bankholidays;

    retain total 0; 
    format date :date9.;

    do i = 1 to nobs; 
        set hash.oyster point = i nobs = nobs; 
            datetime = datepart(datetime);
            format datetime :date9. ;

            if date eq datetime then do;
            total = total + amount; end;
    end;

put "total =" total; 

run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can know when the last observation is executed on a [SET](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000173782.htm) statement by using the END= option (on the SET statement)...however, you cannot use this option with the POINT= option

```
data _null_;
set hash.bankholidays end=first_last;

retain total 0; 
format date :date9.;

set hash.oyster end=second_last;
    datetime = datepart(datetime);
    format datetime :date9. ;

    if date eq datetime then do;
    total = total + amount; end;


if second_last then put "total =" total; 

run;
```

You can absolutely execute multiple SET statements in a DATA STEP...have you tried executing this is in a SAS product IDE (EG or PC SAS) instead of Eclipse?

Comment: So are you saying that the code should run? Thanks for the tip about using last. :)

Comment: I haven't tested it because I don't have any data, but there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the syntax of your code (or mine).

Comment: I found the solution. You need to wrap the set statement in a do loop. Check my answer.